# Python - match a word in a string with a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I'm new to python and I was wondering how string comparison is done

Let's say I have a list of strings containing state names like

```
states = ["New York", "California", "Nebraska", "Idaho"]
```

I also have another string that contains an address like

```
postal_addr = "1234 1st E St San Jose California 95112"
```

How do I parse this address string and find a match with the items in the states list? In the above example, California will be a match. How do I then, after matching, extract `"California"` and store it as a separate string?

Comment: I think we need more details. For example, should `"The New Yorker"` also match? What about an address like `123 Idaho St., Farmville, Nebraska 67890`?

Comment: You are supposed to try first and then ask for help. Otherwise we have the feeling to do your homeworks.

Comment: You're looking for [fuzzy string matching](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=fuzzy+string+matching) .

Comment: That kind of problem will not arise in my case. Because the state name appears only once in the string, and there will not be any scenario like "Idaho St"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
matches = [ s for s in states if s in postal_addr ]
```

Then, if you want to get the string from the postal address:

```
import re
if matches:
    extracted = re.findall( matches[0],  postal_addr)[0]
```

EDIT: ..but this won't work for city/state combos where the city name contains a different state, for example if `postal_adr = '1 Arrowhead Dr, Kansas City, Missouri 64129'` and `states = ["New York", "California", "Nebraska", "Idaho", "Missouri", "Kansas"]` etc. In this case

```
import re
if matches:
    extracted = [(re.search(m, postal_addr).start() , m) for m in matches ]
    extracted = sorted( extracted )[-1][1]
```

Comment: if `len(match)>0:` is not very pythonic, you should write `if match:`. source: PEP8 section Programming Recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> states = ["New York", "California", "Nebraska", "Idaho"]
>>> postal_addr = "1234 1st E St San Jose California 95112"
>>> first_match = next(state for state in states if state in postal_addr)
>>> first_match
'California'
```

However, if you need to match at word boundaries, you might be better off using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
states = ["New York", "California", "Nebraska", "Idaho"]
postal_addr = "1234 1st E St San Jose California 95112"

result = None
for state in states:
    if state in postal_addr:
        result = state

print(result)
```

Unfortunately, this will also match words that contain a state name such as Idahoba.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative answer using a regexp:

```
import re

states = ["New York", "California", "Nebraska", "Idaho"]
pattern = re.compile(r'.*(' + r'|'.join(states) + ').*')

postal_addr = "1234 1st E St San Jose California 95112"
match = pattern.match(postal_addr)

if match:
    state = match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
In [2]: states = ["New York", "California", "Nebraska", "Idaho"]

In [3]: postal_addr = "1234 1st E St San Jose California 95112"

In [4]: ''.join(state for state in states if state in postal_addr)
Out[4]: 'California'
```

Answer (score -1):

To find all matches in the string you could do:

```
matches = [m for m in postal_addr.split() if m in states]
```

Comment: Good point. That makes this a much harder question to answer than the quantity of quick-fire responses (mine included) suggests!